# как правильно программировать многопоточные приложения?

Tags: linux, c, многопоточность

Делаю программу. Первый поток работает с чатом. Второй поток как сервер, принимает данные. Если в первом потоке я могу уследить за данными и выделить их один раз для чата, то во втором потоке данные то сужаются, то расширяются в структуре. Я добавил код, чтобы работать с сетью по dbus. То есть если нет интернет соединения у интерфейса, то не подключаться к сети и не создавать сервер. Если соединение с интернетом установлено, то подключиться к сети и создать сервер. Проблема создаётся, когда я отключаю сеть и подключаю сеть. Программа рушиться, со словами double free. Чтобы отключить потоки я использую pthread_cancel, потому что pthread_kill не помог. Вот в этом и проблема, если не всё освободилось, то потом будет утечка памяти. Хотя в начале функции, где сервер принимает данные, структура в каждом запросе сначала очищает поля, если они есть, а потом создаёт заного. Вот как быть, не могу логику правильно придумать?
Вот ссылка на github [github](https://github.com/xverizex/twitch-bot)

Вот я в одной функции запрещаю потокам выполняться,

```
static void connection_close_all ( ) {
    pthread_cancel ( main_handle );
#if WEBHOOK
    pthread_cancel ( server_handle );
#endif
    const char *body = "Соединение разорвано";
    g_notification_set_body ( notify, body );
    g_application_send_notification ( global_app, "com.xverizex.twitch-bot", notify );
}
```

А в тех потока, которые я отменил, может не успеть освободить память. Как правильно надо делать?

Comment: Код приведите откуда растут ноги. Ничего не понятно.

Comment: @ヒミコ я создал ссылку на github. В webhook.c как раз фукнция, которая работает с памятью. Я не понимаю как лучше сделать, щас переделал под сужение помяти, чтобы не всё освобождать.

Comment: Вы понимаете что никто не станет искать проблему за вас? Укажите на место в коде, приведите его сюда, где происходят сбои, и откуда происходит `double free`.

Comment: А как найти? Я отладчиком gdb проверяю. Но он пишет только на адрес, а текст такой. in ??

Comment: @ヒミコ вы обьясните то хоть как мне с данными работать, если я из другого потока могу с помощью pthread_cancel отменить работу этого потока, и будет утечка памяти. Как мне этого избежать? Я щас попробую какой нибудь код привести, но не знаю, пойдёт ли он.

Comment: @ヒミコ я обновил.

Comment: @ヒミコ а блин, вот я гоню. А вдруг занятая память потоков отдаётся обратно ядру линукс? Или это когда вся программа завершается?

Comment: @ヒミコ я нашёл функцию void pthread_cleanup_push , с помощью неё можно задать, что когда будет отмена потока, чтобы выполнилась эта функция?

Comment: @xverizex, никогда не используй `pthread_cancel`, если не __абсолютно__ уверен, что это то, что тебе нужно... Она требуют написания кода потока по специальным правилам несоблюдение которых в лучшем случае чревато утечками памяти и других ресурсов... для синхронизации потоков используй или флаги, или флаги+сигналы, или трубы/сокеты, или библиотеки более высокого уровня... что именно — зависит от того, что поток делает и как он устроен...

Comment: В любом случае стоит придерживаться правила «поток должен завершать себя сам по внешнему событию». Ни какого внешнего насильного убийства, как с процессами здесь применять __нельзя__ — это порождает больше проблем, чем решает.

Comment: @Fat-Zer, imho от threads чаще всего больше проблем, чем пользы. Но, что тут поделать, модная раскрученная тема...

Comment: @xverizex "Valgrind хорошо известен как мощное средство поиска ошибок работы с памятью. Но кроме этого, в его составе имеется некоторое количество дополнительных утилит, предназначенных для профилирования программ, анализа потребления памяти и поиска ошибок связанных с синхронизацией в многопоточных программах."

http://alexott.net/ru/linux/valgrind/Valgrind.html

Comment: @Fat-Zer ну например я нашел способ, который может разрешает освободить данные перед завершением потока. Это делается с помощью pthread_key_create и ещё нескольких функций. Но было бы проще если бы я делал это на c++, и использовал классы с деструктором, который бы очистил память перед уничтожением локального объекта, да?

Comment: @xverizex, плюсы тут тоже ни чем не помогут... у родных потоков там вообще нет «отменяемости», а pthread про C++ ничего не знает поэтому ни какие деструкторы вызывать не будет... да, `pthread_key_create` — это решение, но использовать его довольно геморройно, а сторонний библиотечный код под него довольно часто вообще подогнать не получится... в данном случае я в принципе согласен с avp: поток тут создаёт больше проблем, чем пользы... тем более раз уже используется glib, то в нём есть готовые примитивы для `poll`'инга сокета...